# How to create a dynamic link?

Tags: php, variables, authentication, hyperlink, dreamweaver

I'm trying to create a link that takes the user to two different pages depending is the user logged or not. Problem is I'm still new to programming and this is quite big bite for beginner like me but its something I have to do. I created something like this so far but either way I suck at searching or there just isnt specific information for what I need

```
<?php if($userLogged){ 
 echo '<a href="index.php" class="stylelink">';
 } 
 else 
 { 
 echo '<a href="index1.php" class="stylelink">';
 } 
 echo "Etusivu</a>";
?>
```

I'm also using Dreamweaver's login function that creates the MM_Username session and such, and Im not sure how to make the condition. userLogged is still an empty variable. Id appreciate any advice.

Thanks
-John

Comment: Do read up on PHP Sessions, if you place `session_start();` at the beginning of each page it allows you to fill the `$_SESSION` variable, of which the contents are saved when you refresh your page. In your session you could save a value which indicates the user is logged in or not.

Comment: I think you should be asking how to create a session and login using Dreamweaver's methods.  Your logic seems fine for creating *dynamic content*.

Comment: your condition with `if ($userLogged)` is good. How do you fill the `$userLogged` var ? You have to check the session's value created by dreamweaver, with these info, you'll be able to set `$userlogged`

Comment: Thank you for responding so swiftly. Im glad to hear theres nothing wrong with that code so I dont have to worry about it anymore. @Marcassin thank you I'll look into it. I doubt theres much else you can tell me, I have to learn the rest myself.

Answer (score 3):

well, instead of using echo statements in the php tag you can write html and use php for outputting the value of the page like this

```
<a href="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']))?'index.php':'index1.php';?>" class="stylelink">Etusivu</a>
```

The `$_SESSION['MM_Username']` works if you have included `session_start();` at the beginning of the page and you can use the condition as above instead of $userLogged.

Comment: Not sure whether this is what the OP wanted to know, but +1 for not using PHP to output the entire HTML.

Comment: @jonne .. as suggested by Marijke, have you added session_start(); at the beginning of the page? Then you simply have to check if $_SESSION['MM_Username'] is set, in the condition `if(isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])){// your redirection here}`